# Dockefile Not running on port

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, tornado

I have this python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop


class RequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
     def initialize(self):
        with open("Desktop/ControlCode/BI.yaml") as f:
            self.write(f.read())

class TEST(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("hahah")

class ONE(RequestHandler):
    
    async def post(self):
        self.write("hoo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", TEST),
        (r"/one", ONE)
    ])

    app.listen(8888)
    print("I'm listening on port 8888")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

And this dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ADD test.py /

RUN pip3 install tornado


EXPOSE 8888

CMD ["python", "./test.py"]
```

When I'm running `docker run -it -d -p 8888:8888 52c097beb9b4`, an image is created but when I go to `localhost:8888/` it is not connecting to it.

Note: If I remove `with open(file)` it is working. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: What OS do you use? Check your firewall. Typical issue for redhat distros (fedora / centos)

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. But the problem seems with with open(file). Since if I remove it, it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script inside the Docker container doesn't have access to `Desktop/ControlCode/BI.yaml` on your host, so I assume [an `OSError` is raised](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) since the file can't be found. Copy the file when you build the Dockerfile and try to access it from within the container. Beware of paths though...

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ADD test.py /
COPY Desktop/ControlCode/BI.yaml /
...
```

And from your script:

```
class RequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
 def initialize(self):
    with open("/BI.yaml") as f:
        self.write(f.read())
```